# UML does business actor need business use case?

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

Can I business actor use normal use case on use case diagram in UML or maybe he needs business use case?

Also I would appreciate explanation of difference between actor and bussines actor.

Comment: Where did you find this bussiness actor?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams/business-subject.png

Comment: In this example I do not see the difference between an actor and your businness actor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer from Vladimir. As answered, there is only use case concept in UML:

UML extension mechanism based on stereotypes permits modeller to give the particurar meaning to general UML concepts.

**Use case model** base semantic idea is to model interactions between **Actors** and **System**. **Use cases** are units of this interaction. By default the context is a software system, so Actors are system users and the System is a software system. Use cases model usage of software system by actors.

"Business use cases" are one of UML extensions, pretty well known. It defines **business actors** and **business use cases** (among other elements).

It shifts the default concret model meaning. System is not more a software system, but rather a Business process. Actor is not a software system user, but rather a business process participant (a worker). A business use case is an interaction between a worker and business process and must not mandatory involve software system.

Back to your question... You should not directly mix business use case elemnts and "normal" use case elements, simply because they live in different apstractions! Thea are interrelated and a business actor can easily give a corresponding system aytor, but they are two sepaarate model concepts.

**An example**:
A business use case could be "Create an invoice", business actor "sales agent". This business task can be performed different ways, e.g. manually and via system.

In the first case (manual), there is no corresponding system use case, because there is no system involved.

In the second case, we could use a software system to enter the invoice. The actor can be a "Sales Agent", but it's a different entity from the first one (although might refer to the same physical person).

Note that the ampping between two models is not 1-1. They will always be quite different as they focus on different abstractions. SOme actors might overlap, some new can be introduced in the system model, some can exist only on business level.

Answer (score 2):

UML does not define business actor or business usecase. It is simply Actor and UseCase.
You can created business model of Bank for example using standard Actors and UseCases. But, methodologies can extend UML elements by stereotypes like "business actor" just to say, that model is defined on business level.It is again standard UML usage.